# Magento 2: Add class to pre existing xml container

Tags: magento2, xml, class-alias

How do you add a class to a pre existing xml block?

Example:

```
<container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
</container>
```

Comment: This question is unclear as to wether you are asking about adding a htmlClass to a block or container please clarify, as the responses assume block, if so you should edit the title to use the word "block" instead of container

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recently I've had the need for the exact same function. I decided to look at the core XML files, and found the following code to work:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info" htmlClass="yourClassName canUseMutipleNames" />
```

I found the above code in the core file at this location:

```
/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

You can use this file as a reference and find some other useful tags like htmlTag :)

Comment: I believe this will throw the error `Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.`

Comment: In Magento 2.2.0 it will throw this error. Also it will throw it for `<referenceContainer>` block

Comment: `<referenceBlock>` or `<referenceContainer>` can  be used for add htmlClass ?

Comment: It can't https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref

Comment: This question has been correctly answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/adding-a-class-to-block-magento-2

Comment: Works fine if using a <referenceContainer>

Answer (score 0):

I have found some code in Magento XML core file

Please Try this code:

container name = "container_name" label="form" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="old-class" after='-'

Answer (score -2):

Since Magento 2.3.2 you need to use [arguments](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument) to referenceBlock/referenceContainer, for container/block use `htmlClass`

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument> 
</arguments>
```

Comment: It does not work with referenceContainer please refer to https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd