# Adding a class to block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, header

I have the following custom xml inside of my Magento_theme > layout > default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link"  after="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Contact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="aboutus.link" after="contactus.link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">About Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
            <reeferenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="false" />

        </referenceBlock>
```

Im removing blocks and adding custom ones in.

What I'd like to to is add a class to the two custom blocks - aboutus.link and contactus.link - how do i go about doing this? Or can it not be done with xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add css as described below by the element

> name="class"

```
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Text</argument>
           <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Text</argument>
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

Comment: adding `class` creates an exception in 2.1.2 => `section source is not supported`, adding `css_class` doesn't create on but then the class is never added

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 ways to do that:-

1- Add wrapping `container` to your `block`, like :-

```
<container name="div.header.links" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header_links" after="-">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links" >

     </block>
</container>
```

2:- Add `referenceContainer` tag, like :-

```
<referenceContainer name="header.links" htmlClass="css_class" htmlTag="div">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header.links">
   <arguments>

   </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Both method are useful .. nice learning

Comment: htmlClass is not used with `<referenceContainer>` https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current` code for version 2.2.6, there is no `class` argument supported (as documented in the previously accepted answer).  However `class` is an accepted `attribute`.  It can be used to set the *css_class* as follows:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Link</argument>
    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">my_page</argument>
    <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="class" xsi:type="string">the-class</item>
    </argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: not work for me . i used both <argument class="class" xsi:type="string">the-classname</argument>
and <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="class" xsi:type="string">the-class</item>
    </argument> 

my current version is 2.2.6 

I include like this 
 <head>
        <css src="css/firstfile.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/>
    </head>

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working! Where do I find documentation regarding these XML layout arguments?